# Program not exiting normally using executorService

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

`newFixedThreadPool(30)` in my program. Here I am starting many task. So when I execute a program its not coming out of run method or exiting the program  normally. If I use `executor.shutdown()` function its exiting. But I want to use executor shutdown only when my server is going down or `JVM` is shutting down. I wanted to know if I am using executors and once the the task is started and if the task has finished executing or I have cancelled it in middle is it like my Thread is still active or is it to take other task (If I am not using shutDown()). If my program is not exiting normally is my program getting stuck somewhere.

Comment: can you elaborate your effort ?

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question for more clarity? especially " If my program is not exiting normally is my program getting stuck somewhere."

Comment: When Iuse ExecutorService in my program.The program is not terminating . Is it because its getting blocked somewhere . I know that using shutDown() function will terminate the program . But if I am not using it does that mean my program is getting blocked somewhere.